# Debian 11 network bridging issue

Tags: debian, bridge

Was hoping someone might be able to help with a bridging issue on Debian 11...  I can't get it to work and I've been tearing my hair out all day!  The bridged interface will not get an IP via DHCP and if you configure it statically it's not accessible.

What I'm trying to do is simple and something I've done many times before.  So to prove I'm not going mad, I've created 2 brand new virtual machines with identical hardware configurations.  One has a fresh installation of Debian 10 (10.13.0) and one with Debian 11 (11.5.0)

Immediately after the OS installation is finished, I log on to each as root and run the command

```
apt-get install bridge-utils
```

Completes as expected on both.

On both, I then open /etc/network/interfaces and set it to:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#allow-hotplug eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp

iface eth0 inet manual

iface eth1 inet manual

iface br0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports eth0 eth1
```

I then reboot both and do:

```
ifup br0
```

Which then works fine on Debian 10:

[image: Debian 10]

But on Debian 11, DHCP fails:

[image: Debian 11]

If you configure the bridge statically then it also works on Debian 10, but not on Debian 11 (the interface isn't accessible and cannot ping in or out)

I can use Debian 10, but I hate not knowing why I can't get something to work, especially after I've spent all day completely baffled!

I'm sure there's some simple change that requires an extra step, but for the life of me, I've not been able to find it!  So any help is very much appreciated.

Edit to add:

Doesn't work on a fresh installation of Debian 11.0.0 (rather than 11.5.0) either.  So it's got to be something fundamental that's changed between version 10 and 11.

Comment: In all cases, the interfaces intended to become bridge ports are down and no configuration is visible to bring them up. Maybe the behavior to bring them up because the bridge uses them changed between Debian 10 and Debian 11.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I can confirm bringing up the bridge interface on Debian 11 also brings up the underlying interfaces too.  It's very strange.  I can only think the packets are blocked by netfilter or something... although all the tinkering I've done with iptables doesn't support that theory,

Comment: What does `ip link` say when it *doesn't work* (after `ifup br0`)? I suspect it doesn't just pull physical NICs up. // Notice that bridge-utils is obsolete and not needed and it is not used even when installed by Debian networking scripts since Debian 10. You can safely remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Bridge-utils now provides hotplug capabilities but you must make sure they are enabled in the file «/etc/default/bridge-utils»:

BRIDGE_HOTPLUG=yes

1. auto br0
2. allow-hotplug br0
3. iface inet br0 dhcp

Answer (score 0):

Try to set bridge_hw with mac address of one of included interfaces (within /etc/network/interfaces).